# Restful web service not responding to ajax

Tags: ajax, rest

I have following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://www.example.com/rest/api.php?request=users",
        dataType: "json",

    }).then(function(data) {
       $('.greeting-id').append(data);
       //$('.greeting-content').append(data.content);
    });
});
```

But cannot see any data.
When I copy-paste url of web-service in browser, it works fine. any idea?

Comment: Maybe `then` has something to do with it?

Comment: 1. Anything in the console log? 2. Is it normal that you have a comma after "json"?

Comment: Look in your console. On the network panel can you see the GET being issued? If so, does it have a response?